# Is this a dominated convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, weak-convergence

We know that a sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ weakly in $L^p(U)$, for some open set $U\subset R^n$ is defined by that for any $g\in L^{p'}(U)$, we have $$\int_U f_ng\to\int_U fg,$$
I just want to know did this has some relation to the dominated convergence theorem? If it is, then what's the dominate function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this situation may happen when the $f_n$ are not dominated by an integrable function. For example, with $\Omega:=\Bbb R$ and $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$. Such a sequence converges weakly to $0$, but the best dominating function is $\chi_{(0,+\infty)}$, a non-integrable one.

The situation "$\Omega$ bounded" is not better, for example when $\Omega:=(0,1)$ and $f_n:=\sqrt n\chi_{(0,n^{-1})}$: it converges weakly in $L^2$ to $0$ and almost everywhere, but there is no dominating integrable function for this $(f_n,n\geqslant 1)$.

Comment: That's great!, how about require $U$ be bounded?

Comment: @vanabel See edit.